# I was hoping someone will be help me to fix my pug error. My home page is working but contact is showing error

Tags: pug

```
extends base.pug

block scripts
    script(src='/static/index.js')

block style
  style
      include ../static/style.css
      include ../static/styleContact.css

block content 
    div.container
    h1 Contact Us
    form(action='/contact', method= "post", class= "myForm")
        input(type="text" class= “name” name="name" placeholder="Enter your name")
        input(type="phone" class= “myInput” name="phone" placeholder="Enter your name")
        input(type="email" class= “myInput” name="email" placeholder="Enter your email")
        input(type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name")
        button(class="btn")
          | Submit
```

**This error is showing in my chrome**

Error: E:\Web design & development\4 javascript\Dance website 75\views\contact.pug:15:34
13|     h1 Contact Us
14|     form(action='/contact', method= "post", class= "myForm")

> 15|         input(type="text" class= “name” name="name" placeholder="Enter your name")
> -----------------------------------------^
> 16|         input(type="phone" class= “myInput” name="phone" placeholder="Enter your name")
> 17|         input(type="email" class= “myInput” name="email" placeholder="Enter your email")
> 18|         input(type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name")

Syntax Error: Unexpected character '“'
at makeError (E:\Web design & development\4 javascript\Dance website 75\node_modules\pug-error\index.js:34:13)
at Lexer.error (E:\Web design & development\4 javascript\Dance website 75\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:62:15)
at Lexer.assertExpression (E:\Web design & development\4 javascript\Dance website 75\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:96:12)
at Lexer.attributeValue (E:\Web design & development\4 javascript\Dance website 75\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1428:10)
at Lexer.attribute (E:\Web design & development\4 javascript\Dance website 75\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1275:30)
at Lexer.attrs (E:\Web design & development\4 javascript\Dance website 75\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1454:20)
at Lexer.callLexerFunction (E:\Web design & development\4 javascript\Dance website 75\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1647:23)
at Lexer.advance (E:\Web design & development\4 javascript\Dance website 75\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1686:12)
at Lexer.callLexerFunction (E:\Web design & development\4 javascript\Dance website 75\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1647:23)
at Lexer.getTokens (E:\Web design & development\4 javascript\Dance website 75\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1706:12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your quote characters: `“name”` might *LOOK* valid, but you need `"` (ASCII 22), not `“` (ASCII E2).  "0xe2" is illegal HTML.